# Exceptionally slow import task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rake

I have a rake task (Rails 3 / Mongoid) that takes a lot of time to complete for no apparent reason, my guess is that I'm doing something multiple times where it's not needed or that I'm missing something very obvious (I'm no MongoDB or Mongoid expert):

```
task :fix_editors => :environment do
  (0...50).each do |num|
    CSV.foreach("foo_20141013_ascii.csv-#{num}.csv", col_sep: ";", headers: true, force_quotes: true) do |row|
      editors = Hash[*Editor.all.collect {|ed| [ed.name, ed.id]}.flatten]
      begin
        book = Book.where(internal_id: row["ID"], editorial_data_checked: false).first

        if book && !row["Marchio"].nil?
          editor_name = HTMLEntities.new.decode(row['Marchio']).strip.titleize
          editor_id = editors[editor_name]
          unless editor_id
            editor = Editor.create(name: editor_name)
            editors[editor_name] = editor.id
            editor_id = editor.id
          end

          if book.update_attributes(editor_id: editor_id, editorial_data_checked: true)
            puts "#{book.slug} updated with editor data"
          else
            puts "Nothing done for #{book.slug}"
          end
        end

      rescue => e
        puts e
        retry
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The CSV I had to read at the beginning was very big, so I've split it in 50 smaller files (that was my first attempt to speed things up).

Then I tried to remove all the queries I could, that's why it doesn't read from the Editor collection for every row but collects all of them at the beginning and then just looks up things in a hash.

At the end I removed all save calls and used update_attributes.

The Book collection is more or less 1 million records, so it's pretty large. I have 13k Editors, so no big deal there.

Here is my Book class:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/087e6c81ef5f355a160d

Locally it takes more than 1 second per row, I don't think it's normal, but feel free to let me know if you disagree. All writes take less then 0.1/0.2 (I've used Benchmark.measure)

I'm out of ideas, can anybody help me? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: it is very hard to say by reading the code - the best advice I can give is to add `puts 'doing XXX'` before each line, and see on what print hangs to identify the problematic line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
editors = Hash[*Editor.all.collect {|ed| [ed.name, ed.id]}.flatten]
```

to the second line right after

```
task :fix_editors => :environment do
```

other thing that you could do batch processing: load 1000 rows, then 1000 books and then process those 1000 books

Comment: `editors = Hash[Editor.pluck(:name, :id)]` should do the job. But I don't think this is the problem since it is only executed 50 times

Comment: @ThomasSevestre no, 50 times multiply by number of rows in each file

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on column internal_id of books table?